# Changing one character in keyboard layout

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I edited the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and added a definition with my new layout as follows

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "us_pl" {
    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (with Polish characters)";
    key <AD06> { [ z, Z, zabovedot, Zabovedot ] };
};
```

I commented the line 27 (for xkb_symbols "basic")

```
// key <AD06> { [   y,  Y   ] };
```

Then I compiled the changed layouts

```
$ xkbcomp -xkm -m basic us
$ xkbcomp -xkm -m us_pl us
```

I set the new layout

```
$ setxkbmap 'us(us_pl)'

$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us(us_pl)
```

Now, I'd like to test my newly defined character but nothing changed. Where am I doing a fault?
Note, that I'd like to change more characters later, so I'd like this example to work.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265937/custom-keyboard-layout-not-active-after-reboot) similar question, which solves part of my problem. There is still the problem with Alt-gr key, which is not working.

I will let this answer here for a while, for others to see the solution and then I will delete it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the AD06 definition of the basic layout.

If you define some 3d level values for a given key, then you need to also define a way to trigger that 3d level.
for example: `setxkbmap 'us(us_pl)' -option 'lvl3:ralt_switch'` (it will define the right alt key (often labelled "AltGr") as the key to switch to 3d level symbols.

You can also add a line: `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` to your "us_pl" definition. Or build it on "us(euro)" instead of "us(basic)"